# Qt C++ preventing program to show error-messages when busy

Tags: c++, qt, window, error-messages-for

Hi I have a question concerning error-messages.

I have a window with several buttons including a OK and Cancel-button. My OK-button executes a program that moves some chart series and for doing so it needs to read in lots of data from a file and shift these values. The Cancel button cancels this operation. The calculations cannot be separated into smaller portions of code.

This works well for smaller amount of data but when I use it with large sets of data the program **acts as if** it crashed. Nevertheless, after some time everything is back to normal, the calculation is done.

There are 2 things I don`t like:

- 1) When I leave the program alone the program changes the headerline of my window to *....(keine Rückmeldung)* which means no response.

  [image]

  After the end of the calculation  the text  *...(keine Rückmeldung)* disappears in the header and everything is back to normal.
- 2) When I try to press the "cancel" button in my window while running the calculation, an additional window appears:

  [image]

  There again, when I leave the program alone and the calculation is finished this window disappears ( as well as the (keine Rückmeldung)  in the header of my window) and and everything is back to normal.

To solve problem 2 I tried to disable my "Cancel" button but this does not help. The slot which is behnid the cancel-button gets executed anyway.

**My question now is: Since I don´t want the user to see these error-messages, is there a way to prevent the program of showing them?**

Thank you

Comment: Is it a continuous chart you are generating ? If yes, then you can use a timer to trigger when you need to draw the chart. Or, if it's only the calculation part which consumes the whole CPU then moving it to some other thread might come handy.

Comment: If you don't want to use threads you can call `processEvents()` from time to time. There are a few classes that have such functions, the basic usage is that from `QCoreApplication`.

Comment: OP, do you have any update?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a [QThread](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qthread.html) for expensive computation tasks. Or better, you can use other built-in multi-threading utilities such as [QConcurrentRun](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtconcurrentrun.html) and [QFuture](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfuture.html).

You can then easily get the state of your background function and show a loading Window, or allow the user to perform other operations in the meantime.